# Odoo calculate total inventory valuation

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How can i get total value of my inventory in Odoo 9 ?.Is there a way to generate a report that shows the total.For example in the picture below the total would be 760000.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the `stock_account` module installed
2. [Activate the developer  mode](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/odoo/usage/debug-mode.html).
3. Go to *Inventory -> Reports -> Inventory at Date*, on the pop-up wizard click *Retrieve the Inventory Value*.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Can the stock valuation be accessed by other users besides the admin ? cant seem to find that option while logged in to other users.

Comment: I think users having _Inventory Manager_ rights should be able to access the menu **in developer mode**.